# How do I make my User class global so I only have to load it in one component and then can use it in other components?

Tags: angular

I tried putting the variable into my Service but it is undefined when I try to use it in my component.

In my 'comment' component I have to use:

```
this.service.GetUser().subscribe( (data) => {
  this.user = data; 
});
```

which does a web request for every single comment on the thread. It's already loaded on higher level component how do I access that instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show you Service and you Component

Comment: My component: https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse/tree/master/wwwroot/app/comment

Comment: My service: https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse/blob/master/wwwroot/app/services/app.service.hackerspulse.ts

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I got your problem, but what about using a `BehaviorSubject`?

It's an observable including the last value.

Your service would have a public property:

`public User = new BehaviorSubject<yourTypeHere>(yourDefaultValueHere);`

All components that wants to use this value, can access it via your service:

`this.service.User.value`

or in a template:

`{{ service.User | async }}`

Or your components can subscribe to it, to get changes..

`this.service.User.subscribe(user => .. something cool ..);`

Your service needs a `refresh` function, which is called first time on `ngOnInit()`..

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.refreshUser();
}

// can be called to refresh User-property...
public refreshUser() {
   this.http.get(...).subscribe(user => this.User.next(user));
}
```

Comment: My goal is just to have an app level global... this would accomplish that?

Comment: Exactly, you have an app-level-global via your service. You should use the BehaviorSubject to be able to be asynchronous, but you could use an normal variable for sure too.. if it fits your needs.

Comment: How would I do it using a normal variable? Is there some way to register my service so that it would be in a global session state? Right now I'm trying to use my service as global session state but the value is undefined when I try to access it (even though it was initialized by higher level component)

Comment: Just declare a "normal" variable insider of you `Service` instead of an `BehaviorSubject` .. That sounds like your `Service` isn't provided at the highest module! If the SAME `Service` should be available to all Modules, Components it has to be `provided` to the AppModule. Otherwise every Module will create a new instance of your `Service`!!!

Comment: Got it to work by using a static user variable in my serivce! argh... feel like an idiot now